# I am getting this error while working on curl code Warning: curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php

I am getting this error while working on curl code  Warning: curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\

```
function curl($pagefile) {      
        $curl = curl_init("https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        $curl = "https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile;
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        //$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
        $loadData = $result;
        print_r($loadData);
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting your resource to a string

```
$curl = curl_init("https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$curl = "https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile;
$result = curl_exec($curl);
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$loadData = $result;
print_r($loadData);
```

change to

```
$curl = curl_init("https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
//$curl = "https://goto.plus/booking/genericwebssi/".$pagefile;
$result = curl_exec($curl);
//$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$loadData = $result;
print_r($loadData);
```

Comment: I changed as you suggested, the error is gone but no result at all.

Comment: @user5527583 - that's a different problem entirely, not Josh's problem to solve.  If you have a new problem, ask it in a new question.

Comment: Try going to the page you are requesting in the browser. I tried going to the base link that you have provided and the source is blank. Does the requested page's source have anything on it?

Comment: what if theres nothing wrong with the link I provided. what are the other possible problem? tnx